# Анализатор логов под все сервисы на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, логирование

Подскажите анализатор логов под Ubuntu. Который сможет без централизованного сбора логов, помогать делать анализ. В данный момент используется следующие пакеты - Samba,ProFTPd, Apache, Nginx, MySQL + системные логи (dmesg, syslog, auth etc)

Comment: что вы хотите достичь у вас 100 серверов или одна ВМ? logstash/netdata/zabbix/elc

Answer (score 0):

Анализатор = он же мониторинг? если речь об периодическом анализе лог файлов с точки зрения поиска проблем...
Рабочий вариант:
можно написать перловый (к примеру) скрипт который будет смотреть ваши логи,
например по крону, раз в 10 минут.

Как вводные данные можно предложить: список путей к лог файлам хранить в хэше.

В переменной $REGEXP (к примеру)список интересующих слов(Warning,error и т.п.)
и наконец в переменной $EXL - исключения (ложные срабатывания ведь бывают :) ).

Для того чтобы не считывать лог файл каждый раз по  новому - использовать промежуточный файл, в который нужно вносить позицию на которую уже файл прочитан.
если есть совпадение - отсылать уведомление (почта,jabber,slack)